# SplashScreen approach defined in xml (without activity) does not appear

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have defined splash screen like many other without external activity, but it doesn't works for me, I don't understand why.

Is there any limitations for images? Also tried for many other images
This is my splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Here preview for splash.xml file in android studio looks like perfectly.
Than I have created style like that

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

and assigned it to activity theme inside manifest

```
 <activity
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

this is my activity's

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

when activity is loaded blank white screen is shown instead of image, maybe for a one second. I searched this approach and seems that it is the same what others were done. Don't understand what's wrong

**EDIT:**
I have tested it for another device OS 5.0 and it works, but for 6.0 doesn't

Comment: You image is not shown at all or it appears only after about 1 second?

Comment: it does not shown at all

Comment: please add your activity.

Comment: ok, updated, it is just only sample oncreate

Comment: you have ``AppTheme`` in ``onCreate`` and ``AppTheme.Launcher`` in manifest. probably ``AppTheme.Launcher`` is overriden by your ``AppTheme``

Comment: nope :/ I have tried without that also

Comment: Ok. I just tested your code (without setting style in onCreate). And it worked. Did you get any errors in logcat? If not put your style ``AppTheme`` also, let us have a look

Comment: nope, seems everything is ok in logcat :/

Comment: now I have tested it for another device OS 5.0 and it works, but for 6.0 doesn't :/

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili please check below answer this is working in 6.0

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili remove **`setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)`** from your activity

Comment: I tried that but had a same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Remove this from your activity

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
```

Try this

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>

</style>
```

**splash_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**SplashActivity**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

        // close splash activity

        finish();
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili check he is setting another theme **setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)**

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili happy to help u

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment. But i cannot put a comment. I have faced the same problem. Please check your size of image. Try to compress the image and try again it may help you. Please do let me know.